# Dali parachain is not in Rococo anymore?

Tags: xcm, rococo, sdk

I’m working on an [SDK for XCM](https://github.com/blockcoders/xcm-sdk) and I made some [examples using Rockmine and Dali](https://github.com/blockcoders/xcm-sdk/blob/main/README.md#send-native-asset-roc-from-rockmine-to-dali). I noticed today the Dali rpc isn't working and isn’t in parachains list in Rococo. I tried to transfer ROC from Rockmine to Dolphin (which has an open HRMP channel with Rockmine), but it didn’t work.
Will Dali be alive again?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please be more concrete and clear here

Comment: The thing is I made some examples using Dali. The first milestone was evaluated using those examples,  now I have to delete them.
It's not a big problem, I only wanted to know if Dali will be in Rococo again. We will send milestone 2 soon and I wanted to use those examples again. Rockmine and Dali was the only parachains combination that worked for me using xcm transfers.